# Выравнивание текста по центру внутри ячейки. Метод GRID

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid

Подскажите как выровнять по центру текст в ячейке с использованием метода Grid. Дело в том что текст в основном окне динамический: может быть и 5 букв, а может и 100 и текст прыгает внутри ячейки.

```
def show():
    # Создание окна
    window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
    window.title("Win")
    window.geometry('1200x800+400+300')
    text1 = Text(window, height=8, width=30, borderwidth = 0,font=('arial',40,'bold'),wrap="word", padx=40, pady=200)
    text1.grid(row = 1, column = 2, columnspan = 3, rowspan = 2, sticky = S)
    text1.insert(1.0, text)
    # Создание кнопки "Click"
    button = ttk.Button(window, text="Click")
    button.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
    # Создание кнопки "Закрыть"
    close_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Закрыть")
    close_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

Comment: Текстовое поле нужно выровнять по центру или текст в текстовом поле? Вообще, добавьте скриншот как получается и как вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в строке:

```py
text1.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=3, rowspan=2, sticky=S)
```

заменить `sticky=S` на `sticky="nsew"` или `sticky="center"`

Comment: center не работает: bad stickyness value "center": must be a string containing n, e, s, and/or w , а nsew по центру не выравнивает